# Spatial Data Cluster in sql-server ? ( like ST_ClusterWithin in Postgis )

Tags: clustering, sql-server-spatial

Postgres 9.5 providing ST_ClusterWithin for Cluster the spatial data in DB level.

Is there any available solution for data clustering in MS SQL (NOT SERVER CLUSTER)

OR

Is there Any Function ( like ST_ClusterWithin ) in MS SQL Server